# Is it possible to somehow run Bukkit on singleplayer Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I am trying to run Skript(a Bukkit plugin), but I want to play alone. Is this somehow possible? BukkitForge hasn't been updated in seven years, and I've tried running a local server, but couldn't get it to work, and also the skript data folder didn't generate. I would like either a suggestion on running *any* Bukkit plugin in single player, or some help with 1) Getting the local server working and 2) Getting Skript to generate the data folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply create an homemade server with IP "localhost"

step 1- create a folder for your server 
step 2- download bukkit and rename the file .jar with "bukkit.jar"
step 3- create a .txt file and insert this inside (without ") "java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar bukkit.jar nogui
pause
"
step 4- rename the file "start" and change the .txt with .bat
step 5- open start.bat (it will close automaticly)
step 6- insert skript in the plugins foler, change the options u want in the server.properties and if u want change the world
step 7- open again start.bat
step 8- open minecraft and insert the ip "localhost" (without ")
!! IF YOU WANT TO STOP THE SERVER, DONT CLOSE THE start.bat FILE, RUN /stop IN THE CONSOLE !!

Answer (score 1):

There is:

**Step 1**: Download bukkit https://getbukkit.org and rename the file to bukkit.jar

**Step 2**: Make a folder at your desired location and name it whatever you want

**Step 3**: Copy the jar to your server folder you just created

**Step 4**: Open cmd or terminal depending on your OS and do

> cd yourFolder/Directory
>
> java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar bukkit.jar

You can replace the 2G with 4G or 1G basically the amount of RAM you wanna use

**Step 5**: Now if you open the folder you should see that there are some new files created if you did everything right

**Step 6**: Open eula.txt and change the 'false' value to 'true'

**Step 7**: Open server.properties and set the server-ip to localhost or 127.0.0.1 which will run the server on your own computer

**Step 8**: Go to your terminal or cmd and type stop

**Step 9**: Type java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar bukkit.jar again or create a bat file for easier access

**Step 10**: Now the server will actually start and you should see the plugin folders and other server folders created now you need to put the plugins you wanna use in it

**Step 11**: Now go to Minecraft then direct connect and type the ip 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1 and there you go you're gonna join the world like a single player only on your computer. The only downside is that you can't pause the game.

Now whenever you wanna play just do that command in terminal

HOPE IT HELPS